# Como copiar los nodos de un Treeview a un Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Necesito copiar los nodos de un TreeView a un TextBox en Visual Studio 2015 asp.net C#. Pero no me aparece la función de AllowDrop o Enable DragAndDrop en las propiedades del TreeView. Alguna idea de como podría hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Hola David, no acabo de entender exactamente lo que quieres. ¿Quieres poder arrastrar un nodo de un TreeView a un TextBox y que entonces el TextBox se rellene con el texto del nodo?

Comment: Así es , ya tengo mi jerarquía conectada de mi base de datos al arbol, y necesito poder copiar las hojas ya sea con DragAndDrop o seleccionar y copiar a un TextBox, no veo ninguna propiedad en mi Treeview de DragAnd Drop así que creo que sería mas de Seleccionar y copiar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El control TreeView no incluye funcionalidad para arrastrar y soltar.

Sin embargo lo que comentas puede implementarse de forma sencilla utilizando una librería cliente como jQuery UI.

Para ello deberás incluir referencias a las librerías jQuery y jQuery UI.
Y el código sería bastante simple:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#TreeView1 a').draggable({helper: 'clone'});
            $('#TextBox1').droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).val(ui.draggable.text());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Este código establece los elementos anchors (`a`) contenidos en el elemento con id "TreeView1" (deberías reemplazarlo por el `Name` de tu TreeView) como "draggables" (elementos que se pueden arrastrar).

A continuación establece el elemento con id "TextBox1" (deberías reemplazarlo por el `Name` de tu TextBox) como "droppable" (elemento al que se pueden arrastrar otros elementos). Cuando se suelta un elemento (función `drop`) obtiene el texto del elemento arrastrado y lo establece como valor del TextBox.

Comment: Muy útil muchas gracias, ahora ya puedo extraer la información del arbol, Ahora con el código ó ID que lleva esa hoja, ¿podría copiarlo al mismo tiempo en un label oculto por ejemplo? a la hora que copio la información de la hoja en textbox? Ya que necesito ese ID para hacer otros Select, ahorita lo estoy trabajando nada más con el nombre pero más adelante podría tener algunos conflictos. Gracias

Comment: `ui.draggable` es un objeto jQuery que es un clón del nodo. Puedes obtener cualquier atributo HTML del elemento. Para obtener el id bastaría con `ui.draggable.attr('id')`